# How to find out queries that run during a migration

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, laravel-5

I have my production server on a shared host where I cannot run `php artisan migrate`. Is it possible that I run the migrate script on my local machine, and manually run the queries that it runs on the production server?

How do I get all the queries run by the `php artisan migrate` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach (doing something by hand a computer is meant to do) seems like a slightly sketchy one given how ubiquitous shared hosts with ssh access are, so step one is find a new job when you're done with this one :)

In the meanwhile, give the following a try

```
php artisan help migrate --pretend
```

This will dump the SQL queries that would run during a migration.

Comment: Oh, the shared host I u̶s̶e̶  used was hand crafted by the devil himself!